# Using iteration variable in Matlab for-loop to access cell/array/struct elements

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, struct, syntax

I have a rather general question regarding the syntax for the for-loop when accessing elements of the (A) array, (B) cell or (C) struct I want to iterate over:

**When (and how) can I access elements in the data I want to iterate over without indexing?** Or the other way around: When do I have to use indices to access data because access only via iteration variable is not possible?

What I mean with accessing via iteration variable will hopefully get clear through the examples below.

---

**(A) Array** (or "Matrix")

```
array = [2 4 6 8 10];
for i = 1:length(array)         % access with index
    fprintf('%i |', array(i));  % is less elegant than ...
end

for number  = array             % access with iteration variable
    fprintf('%i |', number);
end
```

This works for 1-dimensional data and also on 2-dimensional data, where we can access vectors of a 2-d array without indexing:

```
array_2d = [ [2;4] [22;44] [222;444] ];
for vector = array_2d           % access with iteration variable
    fprintf('%s |', mat2str(vector));
end
```

However I haven't figured out how to do this in higher dimensions. Say we have five 8x8 images in an array and want to access them one-by-one. Clearly using indices works, but trying something like `for image = array_3d` will give vectors (same behavior as in the 2d case, only that here we want something else):

```
array_3d = rand([8,8,5]);       % e.g. five 8x8 images

for i = 1:size(array_3d, 3);    % access with index in 3rd dim
    image = array_3d(:,:,i);    % assigning to a new variable is sometimes required
                                % since array_3d(:,:,i)(end) isnt allowed
    last_pixel = image(end);    % e.g. to get the last pixel of the image
    all_pixels = image(:);      % ... or all elements of the image matrix
    fprintf('%s |\n', mat2str(image));
end

% access with iteration variable does not work as intended:
% it will give 5*8 times a 8x1 vector
for image = array_3d;   
    fprintf('%s |', mat2str(image));
end
```

Am I missing some syntactic sugar here to do that? Is there a way to access parts of an array conveniently via iteration variable or is this limited to numbers/vectors?
Or to reframe: Is it possible to do slicing (I think that's what it's called) of matrices using the for-loop without indexing?

---

**(B) CELL**

For cells the limitation of using operators such as `(end)` or `(:)` after indexing doesn't apply, since `cellArray{i}(end)` works. This is good, since I only found solutions that work with indexing:

```
cellArray = cell(1, 3);
cellArray(1:3) = {rand(8,8)};
% create idx from length()
for i = 1:length(cellArray)     % access with index
    cellContent = cellArray{i};
    % ... do stuff with cellContent
end

for cell = cellArray            % access with iteration variable possible
    % BUT cellContent is wrapped in 1x1 cell and needs to be accessed (with) trivial index
    cellContent = cell{1};
    % still this allows to do things like:
    last_pixel = cell{1}(end); 
end
```

Not that it would change anything but make code a bit prettier, but I'm still curious whether it is possible to do without...

---

**(C) STRUCT**

The most elegant access yet in my opinion lies with the struct "objects".

```
structContent1 = num2cell(1:10);
[myStruct(1:10).idx] = structContent1{:};
structContent2(1:10) = {rand(8,8)};
[myStruct(1:10).img] = structContent2{:};

for strctObj = myStruct        % access with iteration variable
    fprintf('%i |\n', strctObj.idx);
    fprintf('%s |\n', mat2str(strctObj.img));
    all_pixels = strctObj.img(:);      % ... or all elements of the image matrix
end
```

However iterating over only one field requires the same "workaround" as when using cell arrays:

```
for image = {myStruct.img}      % access with iteration variable possible
    % BUT needs to be accessed with {1} workaround (see cell access)
    fprintf('%s |\n', mat2str(image{1}));
    all_pixels = image{1}(:);   % ... or all elements of the image matrix
end
```

---

***So basically I am asking: Are there ways to renounce the index access in for-loops?*** I guess I am asking just out of curiosity, for a more object-oriented feel and prettier code.

Comment: Recently I discovered that in MATLAB, its better to do `for i=1:length(A)` because MATLAB will not generate and store the vector, thus saving (a tiny) amount of memory, while arguably being more clear than `for i=array`. My opinion is that in MATLAB (as oposed to python, which is probably the oposite) it is better `for i=1:lenght` than the alternatives. Clearer code, optimized code (by the JIT), less memory.

Comment: In addition, it leads to cleaner code. Just look at yoursecond option in (B). That is quite werid code.